# Trying to pull location info on first connection in linkedin with javascript api

Tags: javascript, json, linkedin-api

I have working code for pulling my connections info from Linkedin.
However, whenever I try to pull location I get strange results.

This code works but you will see 'object OBJECT' where location is supposed to be.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>LinkedIn Industries</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: xxxxxxx
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
scope: r_network,r_emailaddress,r_fullprofile,r_basicprofile,r_contactinfo

</script>
</head>
<body>




<p>This example demonstrates how to retrieve a user's connections.  It also uses the LinkedIn auth events (load, login, logout) to control behavior.</p>

<!-- NOTE: be sure to set onLoad: onLinkedInLoad -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
  IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function() {onLinkedInLogout();});
}


function onLinkedInLogout() {
  setConnections({}, {total:0});
}

function onLinkedInLogin() {
  // here, we pass the fields as individual string parameters
  IN.API.Connections("me")
    .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl","location:(name)")
    .result(function(result, metadata) {
      setConnections(result.values, metadata);
    });
}

function setConnections(connections) {
  var connHTML = "<ul>";
  for (id in connections) {
    connHTML = connHTML + "<li><a href=\"" + connections[id].publicProfileURL + "\">";

    /* picture url not always there, must be defensive */
    if (connections[id].hasOwnProperty('pictureUrl')) {
      connHTML = connHTML + "<img align=\"baseline\" src=\"" + connections[id].pictureUrl + "\"></a>";
    }  else {
      connHTML = connHTML + "<img align=\"baseline\" src=\"http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/icon/icon_no_photo_80x80.png\"></a>";
    }

    connHTML = connHTML + "&nbsp;<a href=\"" + connections[id].publicProfileUrl + "\">";
    connHTML = connHTML + connections[id].firstName + " " + connections[id].lastName + "</a>";
    connHTML = connHTML + " (Location: " + connections[id].location + ")</li>";
  }

  connHTML = connHTML + "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("connectionsdata").innerHTML = connHTML;
}
</script>
<script type="IN/Login">
<div id="connectionstest">
  <p>Current User's Connections:</p>
  <div id="connectionsdata"></div>
</div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main issue really exists in location, in the documentaion this should be replaced with location.name, however, whenever I do this I get nothing back, although I can see that there is a XHR response with a json, which has:

location:{"name":"Dublin etc"}

Please help solve the mystery of the hidden location

EDIT: 5/23/2013-
In Chrome's Developer tools I can see a message saying (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propertry 'name' of undefined - hopes this help someone help me

When I look in the console of the chrome developer, there is more detail on the above uncaught type error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined linkedconnect.html:55

setConnections linkedconnect.html:55

(anonymous function) linkedconnect.html:36
Sslac.Class.Constructor.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.b framework:3242

(anonymous function) framework:173

Sslac.Class.Constructor.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.Method.storedFailureResults 
framework:3247

(anonymous function) framework:173

g framework:3135

pub.incoming framework:801

_window_onMessage framework:566

Comment: If you try the following does it work? connHTML = connHTML + " (Location: " + connections[id].location.name

Comment: Hi HMR, I tried location.name but it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it give you an error, does print an unexpected value? Does it not make you coffee? What does the console say? You can open the console in FireFox and Chrome by pressing F12. You can console.log every  connections[id] and click on them in the console to inspect it's properties.

Comment: HMR, more detail of the console has been added to the above post, thanks for asking. What doesn't work? -I don't get the location of my connections, instead I get 'object OBJECT' where location: name should be, if I try to fix it the page returns nothing

Comment: Thank you for the extra info. I suspect the error happens on line = connHTML + " (Location: " + connections[id].location.name (you can check when clicking on the error where exactly the error occured). It looks like some of the received records might be missing location information.

Comment: yeah, I can confirm that the error occurs at location.name, I will try the code snippet which you posted, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can temporary replace the code setting html with a log of what the connections array really contains:

```
//connHTML = connHTML + "&nbsp;<a href=\"" + connections[id].publicProfileUrl + "\">";
//connHTML = connHTML + connections[id].firstName + " " + connections[id].lastName + "</a>";
//connHTML = connHTML + " (Location: " + connections[id].location + ")</li>";
console.log(connections[id]);
```

When you log an object you can click on it to inspect it's properties, maybe some of the items simply do not contain a location. In that case you can try:

```
function setConnections(connections) {
  var connHTML = "<ul>",
  tmpLocation;
  .....
  tmpLocation= (connections[id].location && connections[id].location.name)
    ?connections[id].location.name:"Unknown";
  connHTML = connHTML + " (Location: " + tmpLocation + ")</li>";
```

Comment: ANSWERED, Thank you HMR   , PS I would vote you up only my reputation is < 15

Comment: You're welcome and no problem, thanks for setting this question as answered it might be of use for future programmers. Hope you know how to use the developer tools (press F12) to track down errors, it will save you a lot of time and headache in the future if you know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message is suggesting you are displaying an object when you are actually trying to display a string. Therefore you need to to pick the correct property of that object:

```
connHTML = connHTML + " (Location: " + connections[id].location.name + ")</li>";
```

Comment: Hi Rob,As stated in my original post, when I use location.name I get nothing back(not even the object OBJECT)

Comment: OK, try calling console.dir(connections[id]) just before the line you wish to use the location and the hierarchy of the object should be displayed in the console. This might shed some light on the cause of the problem

Comment: When I insert that line I see there is an error 'uncaught type error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: "console.dir(connections[id])" does not ask for a property "name". Are you sure you typed it as I said? Is this error new or as a result of my new line?

Comment: I've added more detail of the console output in the original post, thanks!